# Distributions with same mean, variance and kurtosis but different skewness?

Tags: probability

I would like to know if there exists probability distributions (or families) such that I can hold constant mean, variance and kurtosis but can allow skewness to vary? 
Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes. For example, consider the [Pearson family of distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_distribution). If you fix skewness and then specify any give value for kurtosis, that pair will define a particular member of the Pearson distributions. e.g. if you choose kurtosis=10 (excess kurtosis 7), and move skewness from 0 to 3 you pass from type VII (t distribution), through type IV, V (shifted inverse gamma), VI (shifted beta prime), III (shifted gamma) and I (scaled and shifted beta). Numerous posts discuss this distribution family. There are other possibilities as well.